# Plotting a large point cloud using plotly produces a blank graph

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, numpy-ndarray

Plotting a fairly large point cloud in python using plotly produces a graph with axes (not representative of the data range) and no data points.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np


all_res = np.load('fullshelf4_11_2019.npy' )

all_res.shape
```

> (3, 6742382)

```
np.max(all_res[2])
```

> 697.5553566696478

```
np.min(all_res[2])
```

> -676.311654692491

```
frm = pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose(all_res[0:, 0:]),columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])
fig = px.scatter_3d(frm, x='X', y='Y', z='Z')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=4))
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
fig.show()
```

[image: blank plot produced by plotly]

Alternatively you could generate random data and follow the process through

```
all_res = np.random.rand(3, 6742382)
```

Which also produces a blank graph with a axis scales that are incorrect.

So -- what am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to plot such a moderately large data set?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried `matplotlib` ?

Comment: The approach that works is to use open3d.

Answer (score 1):

Try plotting using  [ipyvolume](https://ipyvolume.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).It can handle large point cloud datasets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that's too much data for WebGL to handle. I managed to plot 100k points, but 1M points already caused Jupyter to crash. However, a 3D scatterplot of 6.7 million points is of questionable value anyway. You probably won't be able to make any sense out of it (except for data boundaries maybe) and it will be super slow to rotate etc.

I would try to think of alternative approaches, depending on what you want to do. Maybe pick a representative subset of points and plot those.

Comment: It's a 3d point cloud from a 3d camera.  It will make sense.  I can plot smaller sections of the scan. As regards rotation..I don't really need rotation, if I can show it from a few perspectives. If there is a better python approach to plotting it, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `pythreejs` for a point cloud. It has very good performance, even for a large number of points.

```py
import pythreejs as p3
import numpy as np

N = 1_000_000

# Positions centered around the origin
positions = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=100.0, size=(N, 3)).astype('float32')

# Create a buffer geometry with random color for each point
geometry = p3.BufferGeometry(
    attributes={'position': p3.BufferAttribute(array=positions),
                'color': p3.BufferAttribute(
                    array=np.random.random((N, 3)).astype('float32'))})

# Create a points material
material = p3.PointsMaterial(vertexColors='VertexColors', size=1)
# Combine the geometry and material into a Points object
points = p3.Points(geometry=geometry, material=material)

# Create the scene and the renderer
view_width = 700
view_height = 500
camera = p3.PerspectiveCamera(position=[800.0, 0, 0], aspect=view_width/view_height)
scene = p3.Scene(children=[points, camera], background="#DDDDDD")
controller = p3.OrbitControls(controlling=camera)
renderer = p3.Renderer(camera=camera, scene=scene, controls=[controller],
                    width=view_width, height=view_height)
renderer
```

[image: pointcloud]